# C code mysteriously changing the values of a struct (Interesting mysterious code behavior)

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am implementing a history feature for an example UNIX shell in C.  I have created an array of structs called History, where each struct element contains an integer (the history number) and the command (an array of strings, each string being an argument to the command).  Important parts are denoted ***.

```
struct HistoryElement
{
  int NumberOfCommandGiven;
  char * command[MAXLINE/2+1];
};  

    int main(void)
    {
    char iBuffer[MAXLINE]; 
    char *args[MAXLINE/2+1];
    int bgrnd;           
    int numberofcommand = 0; //The most recent number given to a command entered (for history).
    int currentposition;
    int historysize = 12;
    struct HistoryElement* History = malloc(historysize*sizeof(struct HistoryElement)); //Create an array of HistoryElements.
    struct HistoryElement blank = { -1, "NothingHere" };
    int j=0;
    //clear out any garbage contents of the history and replace with placeholder element called blank.
    for(j=0;j<historysize;j++) {
      History[j]=blank;
    }

    while (1) {           
      bgrnd = 0;
      printf("IansSh: ");
      fflush(0);
      setup(iBuffer, args, &bgrnd); 

      //Test that the entry was stored correctly -- This outputs "ls" before calling history, but after calling history is outputs "history".  How did History[0] get changed???
      printf("History[0].command equals %s \n",History[0].command[0]);  

      if(strcmp(args[0],"history")==0 || strcmp(args[0],"h")==0) { //***
        //WHY is this section rewriting my array of structs?
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<historysize;i++) {
           if(History[i].NumberOfCommandGiven!=-1)
           {
              if(History[i].NumberOfCommandGiven!=0) {
                  printf("%d : %s \n",History[i].NumberOfCommandGiven, History[i].command[0]);
           }
           else {
               printf("%d : Command was removed due to a more recent command of the same entry. \n", History[i].NumberOfCommandGiven);
           }
        }
       }
      }
    //***
    else {
    printf("Got into final else");
    pid_t errorchecker; 
    errorchecker = fork(); //Create child process
    numberofcommand++;
    //Add the command to history: ***
    struct HistoryElement input;
    input.NumberOfCommandGiven = numberofcommand;
    memcpy(input.command, args, sizeof(args));
    History[numberofcommand-1%historysize] = input;
    //Remove any old entries of that exact command from the history, if they exist:
    int k =0;
    for(k=0;k<historysize;k++)
      {
        if(History[k].command==input.command && History[k].NumberOfCommandGiven!=numberofcommand) 
          {
        History[k].NumberOfCommandGiven=0;
          }   
      }
    if(errorchecker < 0) {
      printf("An error occurred when trying to fork a child process.");
      continue;
    }
    else if(errorchecker==0) {
      //Execute the command, of course:
      execvp(args[0],args);
      // Print the error if an error occurred.
      char* err = strerror(err);
      printf("IansSh error occurred (You most likely entered an invalid command): %s: %s\n", args[0], err);
    }
    if(bgrnd==0) {
      //if specified (ie. an '&' was not included), wait on child process to finish before continuing.
      int child;
      waitpid(errorchecker, &child, 0);
    }
      }
    }
    free(History);
}
```

In my code, there is a section specifically for calling the command 'history'.  This of course is not meant to actually add itself to the history as a command, but instead is meant to display the history line by line.  HOWEVER, for some reason, this section of the code is rewriting the values of my array of structs, changing the entry for each command to simply be 'history'.  Thus, when I do testing I get something like:

```
ls -l
(successfully outputs results of ls -l)
ls
(successfully outputs results of ls)
history
1 : history
2 : history
```

When instead, 1 and 2 should correspond to 'ls -l' and 'ls', respectively, just as they were stored in the struct in main.

Comment: maybe you'd like to run your program in `valgrind` and see what it says.

Comment: To what does the "%d" refer to in the else printf? "%d : Command was removed due to..."

Comment: Oops, forgot to include the number in the printf call.  It should refer to the NumberOfCommandGiven for that struct entry in History.  (If the user enters the same command twice, the older one is removed and replaced with that string instead).

Comment: Please show setup - I have a suspicion

Comment: `memcpy(input.command, args, sizeof(args));` copies the pointers not the contents of the strings, and they are overwritten in your setup.

Comment: @rpattiso So, how can i copy the contents of the string, and not the pointers?  Apologies for my noobishness in C, i know that should be easy.

Comment: Can you explain the comment "This outputs "ls" before calling history" ??  The code you have posted will set `History[0].command[0]` to be `"NothingHere"` so you should see that before anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are creating a struct where the second field is `char *[]`

```
struct HistoryElement input;
input.NumberOfCommandGiven = numberofcommand;
memcpy(input.command, args, sizeof(args));
History[numberofcommand-1%historysize] = input;
```

**EDIT:**
First off, as @MattMcNabb pointed out, watch your precedence!
`numberofcommand-1%historysize` is evaluated as `numberofcommand-(1%historysize)` which would have lead to writing off the end of the array (and probably a segfault).

This `memcpy` copies the pointers that are in args, but does not allocate and copy memory for the actual strings in args. for that you will want to iterate through args (instead of `memcpy`) and use `strdup` to create new copies of the strings.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; args[i] != NULL; ++i) {
    input.command[i] = strdup(args[i]);
    if (input.command[i] == NULL) {
          /* handle allocation error */
    }
}
input.command[i] = NULL;
```

You will need to free all these strings later too, so you should no longer overwrite a struct without freeing any possible pointers it has allocated.

```
struct HistoryElement old = History[(numberofcommand-1)%historysize];
int i;
for (i = 0; old.command[i] != NULL; ++i) {
   free(old.command[i]);
   old.command[i] = NULL;
}
History[(numberofcommand - 1) % historysize] = input;
```

But How does the initial `blank` fit into this? We can't free "NothingHere" and that initialization was broken anyway:

```
struct HistoryElement blank = { -1, {NULL} };
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this by the way.  I am working with this code to develop a solution to my problem.  As well as understanding concepts about C which i clearly did not know.

Comment: `1 % historysize` is always `1` (unless `historysize` is `0`, `1` or `-1` that is) so this code is suspicious